# How to find python code of a built-in python operator?

Tags: python, operator, source-code

To my knowledge, some built-in operators are written in python.
This could be handy if I wanted to create a modified version of an operator for my add-on, since I could probably just copy the code and tweak it.

However, I don't know how to:

1. tell if any operator is a python one
2. find its code

In my particular case, I'd like to get the code for `bpy.ops.scene.new(type='LINK_COPY')` (provided it's a python operator) but of course a general method to find operator code would help more than just the code for this one for my future add-on projects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339053/in-python-how-can-one-tell-if-a-module-comes-from-a-c-extension  Re code recommend the `inspect` module.  eg `inspect.getsourcelines(bpy.types.CONSOLE_OT_banner)`  Possibly more a generic python question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, when I do this with an operator, e.g. `inspect.getsourcelines(bpy.ops.scene.new())`, I get a `TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got set'`

Comment: To be expected? If you run op in console it prints `{'FINISHED'}` which is a set.  I doubt also if the output of `inspect.getsourcelines(bpy.ops.scene.new)` will be that useful. Look at `bpy.ops.scene.new.get_rna_type()`   Get the type `bpy.types.SCENE_OT_new` then look at the types execute method.  Since there are no answers maybe rejig Q towards how to get the operator code.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by the "types execute method" and I'm not sure about "rejig Q". I assume it means "clarify the original question and make it more specific"?

Comment: If the type is an Operator it will (most likely) have an execute method. Any yes re Q.

Comment: ok sorry I forgot that "method" was the name for a function inside a class. However, I'm still not sure what's the proper way to find that bit of code.

I did some search using `grep -r SCENE_OT_new` (a search for that string inside a folder on a Linux OS) within the Blender source code and one file popped up (scene_edit.c). Inside it I found `SCE_COPY_LINK_COLLECTION` which is the type of new scene I'm looking for, so I grepped that but all it got me was `SCE_COPY_LINK_COLLECTION = 2` in BKE_scene.h. No code on what the operator does.

Comment: Feels like this is going in circles. That one is written in c. `inspect` will only give python source code.  See comment 1... lol.